# How do most encrypted drives work?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I'm considering a move to hardware encrypted drives. How do these usually work?  I have trouble imagining a drive that self-encrypts. Where do the keys go? It's OK to generalize the answer but I'm a software developer and I've been using software encryption. So I'm at least that savvy. ;-)

Comment: Im sure most of the inner workings of SED's are trade secrets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how better to explain it than this part of an article I saw...

> An SED is a self-encrypting hard drive with a circuit built into the disk drive controller chip that encrypts all data to the magnetic media and decrypts all the data from the media automatically. All SEDs encrypt all the time from the factory onwards, performing like any other hard drive, with the encryption being completely transparent or invisible to the user.
>
> To protect the data from theft, the user provides a password. This password is used by the drive to encrypt or decrypt the media encryption key. In this way even the media encryption key cannot be known without knowing the password.

Extract taken from http://www.computerweekly.com/feature/Self-encrypting-drives-SED-the-best-kept-secret-in-hard-drive-encryption-security at 2:35am 10/01/2015 GMT+11:00.

Comment: Yup, I found that. I was just using the wrong keywords for my searches. Cheese points to ya though. :-)